# Are the two definitions of a Majorana fermion equivalent?

Tags: definition, majorana-fermions

There seems to be two definitions of a [Majorana fermion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion) and I can't work out how to show they are equivalent.

1. The first definition, which is on Wikipedia, is that a Majorana fermion is described by an operator $\gamma$ such that $\gamma^\dagger = \gamma$. This seems to be the condensed matter way to define a Majorana.
2. The second definition is that a Majorana fermion is a fermion for which $\psi^c = \psi$, where $\psi^c = C \psi^*$ and $C$ is the charge conjugation operator. This seems to be the high energy definition.

Are these definitions equivalent? If so, I would greatly appreciate a hint to help me show it for myself.

Comment: That's not a gamma matrix, it's a fermionic operator. I have used the notation used in the wikipedia article

Comment: $\gamma^\dagger=\gamma$ is a Majorana representation of a Clifford algebra $\text{Cliff}_n$. $\psi^c=\psi$ is a Majorana representation of the Lorentz group $\text{Spin}(n)$. Different objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent, and in fact the CM version is not actually a fermion at all, which makes the name extraordinarily confusing.

The HE definition concerns relativistic fields $\Psi$, which are genuine fermionic fields. As with any relativistic field, the solutions to the noninteracting Dirac equation can be expressed as linear combinations of both annihilation operators $b$ and creation operators $d^\dagger$ satisfying the usual canonical anticommutation relations $\{b_s, b_{s'}^\dagger\} = \{d_s, d_{s'}^\dagger\} \propto \delta_{ss'}$ with all other anticommutators zero. In the case of a Majorana fermion field, the "own-antiparticle property" $\Psi = \Psi^C$ holds at the level of the complete relativistic field, and requires that $d = b$; i.e. that the "particle part" and the "antiparticle part" of the field correspond to the same particle ladder operator.

In the CM version, there's no requirement for Lorentz invariance, so the concept of antiparticle is not always well-defined. We often consider the ladder operators to be the more fundamental objects, and work with (non-Lorentz invariant) fields that only have a creation operator without an accompanying annihilator operation. In this case, the (roughly speaking) "own-antiparticle property" applies at the level of the ladder operators: $\gamma = \gamma^\dagger$. This is *not* the case in the relativistic version, where we have the very different requirement that $b = d$. The canonical anticommutation relation $\{\gamma, \gamma^\dagger\} = \{\gamma, \gamma\} = 2\gamma^2 = 2(\gamma^\dagger)^2 \propto 1$ continues to hold, but the canonical anticommutation relation $\{\gamma, \gamma\} = 0$ does *not* hold. So there's no Pauli exclusion principle - you can indeed put two CM Majorana "fermions" into the same mode, but they just cancel each other out and are equivalent to the vacuum. This violation of the fermionic anticommutation relations is what gives them their anyonic statistics, and explains why they're not actually fermions (at least under the usual definition).

(Note that there's a culture clash between the communities as to which commutations relations are the "fundamental" ones. In HE, the relativistic-field commutation relations are postulated to be the fundamental ones, and the ladder-operator commutation relations are just derived results that only make sense in the context of free fields. In CM, the ladder-operator commutation relations are considered to be more fundamental.)

Comment: Hmm, so if I'm reading this correctly, this implies it doesn't even make sense to ask how a CM Majorana fermion transforms under rotations? And when people talk about the massless Dirac fermion in graphene, that's yet another distinct use of the word "fermion", independent of the other two discussed here? And how about Weyl semimetals, is that a fourth distinct thing or is it related to one of the earlier three?

Comment: @knzhou Well even in the relativistic case, the Majorana Lagrangian doesn't have any continuous symmetry, so I don't think it makes sense to talk about how it transforms under rotations either. I believe that the massless Dirac fermion in graphene is an honest-to-goodness Lorentz-covariant fermion field (no anyonic statistics), so it's the same as the HE case. (The "massless" is in analogy with massless relativistic fermions like Standard Model neutrinos.) I can't comment on Weyl semimetals.

Comment: I agree with you that they are too many types of fermions.

Comment: I don't agree that the CM Majorana's do not have $\{a,a\}=0$.  The ones that arise from superconductors, and that CMers are currently interested in do have this property. Perhaps you are thinking of Ising  anyons where fusion rules like $\sigma\times \sigma =1+ \psi$ occur?

Comment: @mikestone By "the Majoranas that arise from superconductors that CMers are currently interested in", I assume you mean the Majorana zero modes that arise at the ends of Kitaev chains, which can be physically realized in $p$-wave superconducting nanowires? Majorana zero modes *are* Ising anyons, and have those fusion rules that you list. And they do indeed have $\{ \gamma, \gamma \} = 2$ rather than $\{ \gamma, \gamma \} = 0$ (I edited my post to use the more common letter for Majorana creation operators).

Comment: @mikestone See https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04103 or http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~pelster/Anyon3/baranov-slides2.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not equivalent. One is a property of a single mode, one is the property of a  particle  being its own antiparticle. For 2d relativistic space-time  one can expand the field for a  chiral  right-going  particle  as 
$$
\psi(x,t)= \sum \hat a_k e^{ik(x-ct)},
$$
and the condition of it being the field of a Majorana particle will be $\hat a_k= \hat a_{-k}^\dagger$. There will be a Majorana mode in the CM sense if $k=0$ is an allowed value of the momentum so that $\hat a_0= \hat a_0^\dagger$.

The terminology is not *deliberately* confusing, but the two things are often conflated in news releases.

Comment: Hmm, so all CM Majorana modes have zero momentum? But I could’ve sworn I’ve heard the term used in CM more generally than that...

Comment: @knzhou No, I think he's starting from the HE definition and then saying that the only mode that *also* obeys the CM definition must have zero momentum.

Comment: @tparker Well, I've been wondering for literally years what the CM definition actually is (in terms of representation theory) -- mind posting an answer?

Comment: @knzhou I'm not familiar enough with representation theory to comment on that, but I posted what I know.